# Where are some good documentation for this open source project 'solr-uima'

Tags: solr, uima

I'm really interested in being able to annotate my data.  I am not really sure where to start, so I thought of using Apache Uima with Solr.  I'm not sure if I'm no the right path, yet.  Anyhow, I'm looking for some good documentation on this component called Solr-Uima

http://code.google.com/p/solr-uima/

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what UIMA is, but when I can't find any docs I [read the tests](http://code.google.com/p/solr-uima/source/browse/trunk/solr-uima/src/test/java/org/apache/solr/uima/processor/UIMAUpdateRequestProcessorTest.java). If the tests are not enough I read [the code itself](http://code.google.com/p/solr-uima/source/browse/trunk/solr-uima/src/#src%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fapache%2Fsolr%2Fuima%2Fprocessor%253Fstate%253Dclosed). (sorry if this is a generic answer, but this code doesn't seem to be too difficult to follow, so I really think it's a viable option).

Comment: Also has to do with the fact that I'm not too familiar with Uima myself :)

Answer (score 0):

The former project on Google Code has been contributed to Lucene / Solr [codebase](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/contrib/uima/).

There is a [wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrUIMA), but needs to be updated.